# run 2 queries in sql at the same time with SELECT column as

Tags: php, sql

i am running this query in SQL:

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) as agent_counter
    FROM ast_queue_log 
    WHERE event = 'COMPLETEAGENT'
```

i want to also do

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as caller_counter 
FROM ast_queue_log 
WHERE event = 'COMPLETECALLER'
```

can i run these in the same query?

Comment: What is your SQL Flavor? Does it support `CTE`s?

Answer (score 0):

This will group the result by the event type, and tell you exactly which event and how many

```
SELECT `event`, COUNT(1) AS `counter`
FROM `ast_queue_log`
WHERE `event` IN ( 'COMPLETEAGENT', 'COMPLETECALLER' )
GROUP BY `event`
```

Results (sample):

```
COMPLETEAGENT    10
COMPLETECALLER   5
```